# Is it possible to add automatically not installed libraries in Altium?

Tags: altium

As the title says: Is it possible to add automatically not installed libraries in Altium ?

After I reinstall Altium all the libraries I have added are not there I have to add them one by one again looking through every component I have.

Is any way to force Altium to analyze Library directory and search for missing libraries in my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Two solutions:

### 1. Search Path

Add your library path to the system search path. It will look there to find any missing libraries.

To do this, use the "Available Libraries" dialog and select the "Search Path" tab. Add your path to the list.

### 2. Install Libraries Globally

Install your libraries at the system level then all your libraries will be available in all of your projects.

To do this use the "Available Libraries" dialog, "Installed" tab (you'll have to switch as it is not the default tab when the dialog opens and it looks identical to the "Project" tab layout).

Click the "Install" button and shift-select all of your libraries.

[image]

Comment: Having them in different folders, as ussualy one gets store them, make this to select each file individually...?? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Besides, when i go to the dialog Search Path options, it only seeks me `*.PcbLib` files, and not `*.IntLib` files... do you know why that happens?

Comment: @hyprfrcb -- You can add folders in the "Search Path" tab. The "Project" and "Installed" tabs require specific individual files, but you can use shift-select in the "Install" dialog to install many individual files at once. You can change the type from "PcbLib" to "IntLib" in the "Install" Dialog using a filter box in the lower right corner (IIRC).

Comment: How does one locate the "Available Libraries" dialog?